# RewriteEngine config

Tags: html, mod-rewrite

My website is coded on a way that instead send on from, input, etc thigs such as `index.php?subtopic=register&step=1`, `index.php?subtopic=account&page=login`, etc it sends out just a `/account`, or `/register`... I'm a amateur when it comes to web, but I searched a little and I started to make a `.htaccess` file like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?subtopic=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^home/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?subtopic=home [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^characters/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?subtopic=characters&name=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^register/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?subtopic=register&step=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It does seen to work, but soon I realized that there is too many variables to fill, it does not seem right.. Sorry for ask, I think that it should be very simple, but I'm not figuring out this..

Comment: Did you enable the interpretation of such `htaccess` style files at all? You can easily check that by placing an obvious syntax error in that file. Do you really get an error then?

Comment: And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using `.htaccess` style files. Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Yes I enabled htaccess, I tested it before. Without this first rule "RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?subtopic=$1 [L,QSA]" the pages from the website don't work by clicking on links (that redirect to /pagename instead index.php?subtopic=pagename)

Comment: So what is your actual question then?

Comment: The problem I think is that I have to list a rule for every variation on this scheme, like ^characters/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?subtopic=characters&name=$1

Comment: I'm doing something wrong? Because it does not seems right to me. EDIT: As I said, I'm amateur when it comes to web, I need to know if I'm doing it the right way ^^' Thanks

Comment: I added an answer below showing a more general approach. However sometimes it makes more sense to keep things readable by preferring explicit rules. Somewhat a question of effort and personal preference...

Answer (score 0):

From the comments to the question it becomes clear that your are asking for a more flexible way to handle the different tokens before the first slash ("characters" or "register").

You certainly can grab those tokens by a pattern too in a flexible manner:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?subtopic=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?subtopic=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Certainly you will have to make sure that this strategy actually is correct for *all* requests matching that pattern. So you might have to add some exception to that general rule...

---

This would be a slightly modified version which I would recommend to prefer. Using an optional leading slash (`^/?` instead of just `^`) allows to use the same rule set in the real host configuration which always is preferable to using `.htaccess` style files:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?subtopic=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?subtopic=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hm - I tried something similar yesterday I think, but this rules results in internal error. Not sure why. Also, I'm using htaccess only because I dont need to restart apache when I need test other rule.

[Tue Dec 06 14:46:24.199611 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5853] [client 192.168.0.3:53722] /var/www/html/.htaccess: RewriteRule: cannot compile regular expression '^([^/])+)/([^/]+)/?$'
[Tue Dec 06 14:46:24.407634 2016] [core:alert] [pid 2974] [client 192.168.0.3:53723] /var/www/html/.htaccess: RewriteRule: cannot compile regular expression '^([^/])+)/([^/]+)/?$', referer: http://192.168.0.148/

Comment: @FelipeMuniz Restarting the apache http server can be done using the `graceful` restart option which takes about one second and does not disrupt any currently active sessions. There are _many_ good reasons to prevent the usage of `.htaccess` style files, so you should at least consider moving things after you found a solution.

Comment: @FelipeMuniz Sorry, there was an obvious typo in the pattern, thanks for mentioning that, fixed it.

Comment: ^^ Thanks. Is there any way that I can make "name" variable on the rule to meet what comes after the first slash? Because this changes from topic to topic, like in characters is "name", in register is "step", etc..

Comment: @FelipeMuniz Ah, sorry, I missed that detail ;-( No, I do not see an easy way to have such flexibility, you'd obviously need a dictionary, so a rewrite map for that which only makes things more complex. In that case I would recommend to configure separate rewrite rules in an explicit manner.